# When using Angular @Input decorator, Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript

My problem is related to Angular `@Input()` decorator, as when I am using this decorator, typescript throwing error, not when using in regular code.

In my `child.component.ts` file I am declaring this decorator to get props from parent component :

```
@Input() customColumns: {
    name: string;
    index: number;
    type: 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button';
    icon?: any;
    url?: string;
  }[] = [];
  indexList: number[] = [];
```

And in my `parent.component.ts` file I am assigning the value for this variable like this :

```
customColumns = [
    { name: 'permissions', index: 7, type: 'icon', icon: faSave },
    { name: 'price list', index: 6, type: 'link', icon: faArrowDownWideShort },
    { name: 'details', index: 5, type: 'button', icon: faArrowUpWideShort },
  ];
```

Lastly, in my `parent.component.html` file I am calling that child component:

```
<app-child [customColumns]="customColumns">
</app-child>
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "link" | "image" | "icon"'.

But when I am doing same thing in normal typescript or ngOnInit() function it is working, can't figure out why it is happening, help me please, thanks in advance.

```
    let customColumns: {
      name: string;
      index: number;
      type: 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button';
      icon?: any;
      url?: string;
    }[] = [];

    customColumns = [
      { name: 'permissions', index: 7, type: 'link', icon: '' },
      {
        name: 'price list',
        index: 6,
        type: 'icon',
        icon: faArrowDownWideShort,
      },
      { name: 'details', index: 5, type: 'icon', icon: faArrowUpWideShort },
    ];
```

My project dependencies:

> ```
> "@angular/cli": "~14.2.7",
> "typescript": "~4.7.2"
> ```

Comment: You can set type?:any

Comment: I can, but I want to restrict that , others can only assign 4 options or string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replicate the same behavior in normal TypeScript you should use this scenario:

```
let customColumns: {
  name: string;
  index: number;
  type: 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button';
  icon?: any;
  url?: string;
}[] = [];

const anotherValue =  [
  { name: 'permissions', index: 7, type: 'link', icon: '' },
  {
    name: 'price list',
    index: 6,
    type: 'icon',
  },
  { name: 'details', index: 5, type: 'icon', icon: '' },
];
customColumns = anotherValue;
```

That's simular to Angular typecheck code.

In order to solve it you can use either predefined enum:

```
const enum ColumnType {
  icon = 'icon',
  image = 'image',
  link = 'link',
  button = 'button',
}

let customColumns: {
  name: string;
  index: number;
  type: ColumnType;
  icon?: any;
  url?: string;
}[] = [];


...
type: ColumnType.link,
```

or `as const`:

```
type: 'link' as const
```

Comment: `type: 'link' as const,` I can't do this in angular, I have to declare interface for it . My problem is not normal typescript, but it is angular @Input (), where it is not working. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Anyway? I showed behavior in simple ts but gave you Angular solutions.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zpiywx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But I prefer enum https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmrhr1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The enum isn't strictly necessary, a simple typedef for the column type should be enough. `typedef ColumnType = 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button';`

Comment: @JeffMercado With `type ColumnType = 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button';` you have to use `as const`  or `as ColumnType` again  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcgwxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

1.create a class like this

```
export class CustomColumns {
constructor(
public name?: string,
public index?: number,
public type?: 'icon' | 'image' | 'link' | 'button',
public icon?: any,
public url?: string
){}
}
```

2.and in your child component use like this

```
@Input() customColumns: CustomColumns;
```

Comment: I already have done same thing, as you mentioned. It is working , as I described in my question, but not working , when I am using @Input () , instead of let.

Comment: I edited my answer dr. please check it now.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Can you accept my answer dr

Comment: But, he gave me stackbiltz link, so he deserve it more, I think. But you are cool also, happy coding.

Comment: Oh yes he deserve that. I just saw his answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249608/discussion-between-mehdad-hussain-and-dinuka-silva).